# Get the limited items of each type grouped items laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, group-by

I have a table called `books` and another table called `categories` and it has `item_id, type , and others ..` columns in `categories` and `type` in `enum (1/2/3)`

Now I am trying to get the limited items of each group like 3 items from each type
So for that I am trying to get the 9 categores 3 each which has different type

Like This

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2067 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2060 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2055 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
    3 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2026 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I have tried this with .

```
$categoryLists = Category::where('display_at_home', 1)->limit(3)->get()->grouBy('type');
```

But it is not doing the work

Comment: No sure if this is your issue, but you have this is wrong:  ```grouBy('type')```.  Should be ```groupBy('type')```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Eloquent Eager Limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) package as follows.

```
class Book extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
    
    ...
}

class Category extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

    ...
}
```

Then to get the relation you desire, you can do:

```
$categoryLists = Category::where('display_at_home', 1)
                         ->limit(3)
                         ->with(['books' => function($query) {
                             $query->limit('3');
                         }])
                         ->get();
```